# Call two commands on a button click - one in ViewModel one in code behind

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

Button control:

```
<Button Content="OK" Grid.Row="2" IsDefault="True" Style="{StaticResource ButtonFormStyle}">
            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
                    <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding RequestConfigurationCommand}" />
                    <!--<i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding ValidateCommand} />  doesn't work --> 
                </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
        </Button>
```

ViewModel - DataContext of the view:

```
RequestConfigurationCommand = new RelayCommand(ExecuteRequest);
private void ExecuteRequest()
{
    Validate();

    DoStuff();
}
```

xaml.cs:

```
private void ValidateCommand()
{
    // Do some stuff
}
```

So, how can I do this? And is this possible?

Comment: Don't use code behind for Views. And on a side note, don't use ViewModels on user controls

Answer (score 3):

you can use the button click event in this case first click event will fire then command will fire so

```
<Button Content="OK" Grid.Row="2" IsDefault="True" Style="{StaticResource ButtonFormStyle}"
        Click="btn_click">
```